# i want to implement separate chaining hashing in c. but the code is running out of memory in the createhashtable function

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define LOADFACTOR 5


struct listnode
{
    int key;
    int data;
    struct listnode *next;
};


struct hashnode
{
    int bcount; //block count 
    struct listnode *next;
};

struct hashtable
{
    int size;
    int count;
    struct hashnode **table;
};

struct hashtable * createhashtable(int s)
{

    struct hashtable * h = (struct hashtable*)malloc(sizeof(struct hashtable));
    //if(!h)
    //retur

    h->size = s/LOADFACTOR;
    h->count = 0;
    h->table = (struct hashnode **)malloc(sizeof(struct hashnode *) *  (h->size));
    if(!h->table)
    printf("memory erroe");
    int i;
    for(i=0;i< h->size;i++)
    {
        printf("a");
        h->table[i]->next = NULL;
        h->table[i]->bcount =0;           giving error in this for loop
    }
    return h;
}
int hash(int size , int item)
{
    int index = item %size;
    return index;
}

int hashsearch(struct hashtable * h , int item)
{
   struct listnode *temp = NULL;

   temp = h->table[hash(h->size,item)]->next;
    while(temp)
    {
        if(temp->data == item)
        return 1;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return 0;
}

int insertintohash(struct hashtable *h , int item)
{
    int index;
    struct listnode * newnode ,*temp;

    if(hashsearch(h,item))
    return 0;

    index = hash(h->size,item);
    temp = h->table[index]->next;
    newnode = (struct listnode *)malloc(sizeof(struct listnode));
    if(!newnode)
    {
        printf("out of space");
        return -1;
}
    newnode->key = index;
    newnode->data = item;
    newnode->next = h->table[index]->next;
    h->table[index]->next = newnode;
    h->table[index]->bcount++;
    h->count++;
return 1;
}


int main()
{

struct hashtable * h = NULL;
h = createhashtable(60);    

if(insertintohash(h,5))
printf("successfully inserted");
return 0;



}
```

the createhashtable function is giving run time error while assinging every hashtable node next pointer to NULL

the for loop used in the createhashtable is giving run time error please just me a solution

Comment: Well, what error are you getting? And when? First time? (Try changing `a` to `a\n` so you can see them print -- probably stuck in buffer without the newline.)

Comment: problem is not with a .. problem is with   h->table[i]->next = NULL;
        h->table[i]->bcount =0;

Comment: Yes, I just meant that it would help you see how many times the loop was executing. It might execute several times without seeming to print `a` because of buffering. **What error message are you getting.**

Comment: if i comment h->table[i]->next = NULL; h->table[i]->bcount =0; these two statements then loop is executing for 12 times else it is printing a for three time and then it is running out of memory

Answer (score 1):

`h->table` is pointer to pointer to `struct hashnode`. You allocated a
list of 12 pointers to `struct hashnode`. These pointers are not
initialized. You need to do this first inside the loop:

```
h->table[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct hashnode));
```

With suitable error checking, of course.